# Why are my char-to-byte conversions not working in Python?

Tags: python, character, byte

I'm trying to understand converting data to bytes in Python. I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here. This question may help to clear up some of my misconceptions. Among other things, I want to break a string up into characters and convert each character to a byte. Here are six different attempts I made to do so. What am I failing to grasp?

```
import sys

data = 'String'

a = data.encode('utf-8')
print(a)
for byte in a:
    print(sys.getsizeof(byte)) # I expect to get 1; I get 14.

b = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
print(b)
for byte in b:
    print(sys.getsizeof(byte)) # I expect to get 1; I get 14.

c = bytearray()
c.extend(map(ord, data))
print(c)
for byte in c:
    print(sys.getsizeof(byte)) # I expect to get 1; I get 14.

for char in data:
    d = char.encode('utf-8')
    print(d)
    print(sys.getsizeof(d)) # I expect to get 1; I get 18.

e  = data.encode('ascii')
print(e)
for byte in e:
    print(sys.getsizeof(byte)) # I expect to get 1; I get 14.

bytearray = (b'ABCD')
for each_byte in bytearray:
    print(sys.getsizeof(each_byte)) # I expect to get 1; I get 14.
```

Comment: Ah. Well, len(byte) won't work for a, b, c, e, or bytearray. I get:


TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()


But it works for d. This might help me understand it well enough to write my larger program. Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, iterating over a bytes object actually gives you an `int`